# Invalid arguments supplied for foreach() in custom phtml magento2

Tags: magento2

What is invalid in the `foreach` in my custom phtml template?

```
$filters = $helper->getMyFilter();

<?php foreach ($filters as $key => $filter): ?>
```

I am getting

> Invalid arguments supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

`$filters`  may not be an array, that is why it isn't working.

Try to use

```
if (is_array($filters) || is_object($filters))
{
    foreach ($filters as $key => $filter)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or

```
foreach ((array) $items as $item) {
 // ...
 }
```

Comment: Will update, haven't checked that part for a while @Krishna